# Как обеспечить базовый уровень безопасности VPS/VDS сервера?

Tags: безопасность, хостинг, vps

Приветствую. Не так давно стал использовать VPS/VDS сервер, поэтому возник такой вопрос - что нужно сделать, чтобы устранить явные дыры в безопасности? Меня интересует именно настройка сервера, не безопасность в скриптах и программном коде. Сервер работает на Ubuntu. Хотелось бы услышать общие рекомендации и на что стоит обратить внимание.

Comment: Убедитесь в том, что аутентифицировать и авторизоваться можно только тем способом и с теми привилегиями, котоыре вы хотите (я подозреваю, что вы захотите сделать аутентификацию исключительно по публичным ключам и закрыть доступ для рута), и что все сервисы, пингуемые снаружи, также имеют привилегии не больше необходимых (= работающий PHP выполняется от какого-нибудь www-data, который, в свою очередь, не может писать в /etc). Столь модная изоляция внутри контейнеров (или немодная chroot) позволит вам закрыть хост-систему от просмотра, даже если у вас "угонят" демон, что спасет секреты в /etc.

Comment: @Etki нужно закрыть доступ для рута и создать других пользователей с нужными привилегиями, так? А чем это выгодно?

Comment: В этом случае злоумышленнику придется подобрать логин, публичный ключ и приватный ключ некоторого пользователя, что с текущими технологиями просто невероятно. После этого для доступа к повышенным привилегиям ему придется подобрать еще и пароль пользователя. Про рута же злоумышленник знает, что такой пользователь есть, и в случае, если там условный восьмисимвольный пароль, за разумное время долбежки перебором он сможет получить доступ, который так хочет.

Comment: Кроме того, имеет смысл поднять еще и fail2ban. При вышеописанной схеме он не даст гигантского прироста в безопасности, но заранее отвадит любителей побрутфорсить.

Answer (score 1):

Если ставили из официального релиза, вся безопасность уже есть.

Если вы будете единственным реальным пользователем в системе, то дополнительно делать ничего не надо. Все просто: вам не нужно разграничивать права. Исключение - системные пользователи (memcache, mysql, www-data), но опять же, `apt-get` уже все сделает за вас. Системные пользователи имеют номера до 1000 (`cat /etc/adduser.conf | grep FIRST_GID`, `cat /etc/passwd`). Постоянно работать под `root` все равно не безопасно.

В случае такого "монополизма" пароль на MySQL ставить не обязательно, так как по-умолчанию он слушает только `localhost`. Более того, `memcache` и `Mongodb` по-умолчанию ставятся без пароля, так как доступны только с `localhost`, а время, когда на одном сервере работала куча пользователей (бухгалтера, программисты, etc), которых нужно было "фильтровать" по доступам, прошло.

`root` также по-умолчанию отключен, а веб-сервера работают под `www-data`.

`fail2ban` я бы не стал ставить, если у вас криптостойкий пароль (попробуйте команду [apg](http://rat.admin.lv/?p=235)), логин не `root` и у вас не паранойи. Можете чуть позже посмотреть по логам - будет брутфорс рута, а имя вашего пользователя никто кроме вас не знает. А сервер не сообщает, что такого пользователя нет. Это мое ИМХО.

А вот действительно важные вещи - своевременное обновление ПО (мой первый шаред сломали через уязвимость в каком-то графическом пакете). Наверняка слышали про громкие уязвимости типа heartbleed и Meltdown. Также не выполняйте без анализа сомнительные скрипты, скачанные на каком-то там форуме.

Второе - правильная настройка устанавливаемого ПО, тут по обстоятельствам, смотрите документацию.

- решили сделать `ftp` - будьте готовы к утечке паролей, так как логин-пароль будет передан через несколько серверов в открытом виде. Альтернатива - `sftp`. Рекомендую также чрутинг [chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29)
- даете другу попользоваться сервером - `chroot`, пароль на MySQL, `open_basedir` и запрет на `shell_exec` и другие аналогичные функции для PHP (см. `php.ini`).

Третье. Чаще всего ломают через уязвимости в веб-скриптах. Это отдельная большая тема. Примеры:

- утечка исходного кода и паролей сайтов из репозитория `.git` в корне веб-документов. Добавьте блокировку через правило `.htaccess` (apache) или nginx или создавайте репозиторий выше корня веб-документов.
- разрешите писать веб-серверу только в единственный каталог - "загрузки" (`upload/`, `media/upload/`, etc), а выполнение скриптов из этого каталога - запретите
- используйте git, с его помощью возможно понять "что поменялось"
- не используйте сомнительные сборки CMS и регулярно обновляйте их версии
- если вы - разработчик, обязательно прочтите про XSS и SQL инъекции

Если вы решили зайти еще дальше, то:

- [SELinux](https://habr.com/post/322904/)
- Zabbix
- logwatch, logcheck, auditd
- [20 советов по повышению безопасности сервера Linux](http://ubuntulinux.ru/config/napilnik/20-linux-server-hardening-security-tips/)

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, есть организация с именем Center for Internet Security, которая публикает [внушительные документы](https://learn.cisecurity.org/benchmarks) по теме - в том числе, например, [Ubuntu 14.04 Benchmark](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/linux/CIS_Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_Server_Benchmark_v1.0.0.pdf)